# How does modifying generics in interface affect backwards compatibility

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

I have an interface like this,

```
public interface EventListener<T extends Event>
```

the problem here is that `EventListener` is an extremely generic name (which can also be said about `Event`) and the class `Event` is not written in a generic way.

Since we are not allowed to do non-backward compatible changes the plan was to modify the generic part of the interface to be more general. So basically I have two options. Either,

a) Add a super interface (eg. `GeneralEventListener`, let's not mind the name right now) which can take a generic without discrimination

```
public interface GeneralEventListener<T>
```

b) Allow `EventListener` to take an object of type T.

```
public interface EventListener<T>
```

I am sure the first one is an allowed modification. However this seems like an unnecessary complication and it would contaminate the namespace. There are neither any need to keep the limitation to `Event` except from formerly informational. So what I wonder, "is the change (b) binary backwards compatible"?

Comment: will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493452/can-i-recompile-a-public-api-with-a-sub-interface-and-keep-binary-compatibility/43503782#43503782

Comment: @Eugene Not really. This was rather about abstract methods. I am more looking into allowing a larger subset of types allowed for the generic part. It is fairly clear why this would not work, but I see no bigger gains in enforcing generic limitation of typing in an interface. I guess there might be some very rare case, but generally this seems like a harmful limitation making the code less reusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was not completely correct.

This will cause an issue. Due to the fact that you are using a bounded type, the compiler will replace the type parameter with the bounded type.

Have a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Of course because generics are used at compile time, your best bet would simply be to make the change and see if the code compiles.

Comment: Ok, this could impose a problem since the Interface is public. Thank you for the answer though.